# Codenameone list scrollbar quetions

Tags: codenameone

I have a list and its scroll bar on the right along with two custom buttons representing upscroll and downscroll. These two buttons simulate scrolling by using list.setSelectedIndex(index, true) and are placed above and below my scrollbar via my custom layout.

I have two questions regarding this:

1). Since the upscroll and downscroll buttons are overlayed on top of the list, they disappear when i click elsewhere..and they kind of flash into appearance when i click the area it's supposed to be in. How can I remedy this behavior?

2). I have a scrollbar image that I have used in the "Scroll" theme in the GUI builder. It's alignment is IMAGE_ALIGNED_CENTER. However the scroll thumb doesn't reach the end of the bar when i scroll to the end of the list via my upscroll and downscroll buttons. The upscroll and downscroll buttons essentially scroll the list by one index with each press (using setSelectedIndex(index, true)).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you overlay the buttons. I'm assuming you just set them into a specific location which disallowed as we can't possibly adapt them to the various resolutions. I suggest reading the [developer guide section on layouts](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html) very carefully.

To place something on top of the list in a portable way you need to use the `LayeredLayout` or the `LayeredPane` and a `Container` + correct layout to position this within (e.g. `BorderLayout` `EAST`).

In this [blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/permanent-sidemenu-getAllStyles-scrollbar-and-more.html) there is a sample for making a scrollbar but it isn't "on top". It can be used as a starting point.